# how to write an iphone app for an external website when there are NO REST APIs?

Tags: iphone, html, rest

Hi 
Sometimes a website do not have a mobile version, for example, stackoverflow.com or most php forums
There are no REST APIs or APIs are very limited.
In this case, is it possible to write an iphone app that combine the native UI and content from websites?

I googled but hard to get useful results.
Where can I start from? Are there some open source example?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @user533077: stackoverflow have an API(http://stackapps.com/) and phpBB and probably many forum have some extension to make API.

Comment: Thanks that you mentioned stackoverflow APIs. I am taking stackoverflow.com as an example for poor experience on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StackOverflow has an API -- here's an Objective-C wrapper

https://stackapps.com/questions/1194/corestack-an-objective-c-library

If it didn't have an API, the easiest way is to just use a UIWebView in your iPhone app.  Otherwise, you'd need to scrape the site which might be against its Terms of Service.

If you need to do this, then scape it into your own database and make your own REST API for it, or in some other way proxy it so that you can correct for changes to the website.

Comment: when you talk about database, is the database located on phone or some external server that I have control？ Thanks

Comment: You make the database, put it on a server, then build your own REST API for it with a webserver and any web framework you like.  You fill the database using a webscraper.

Comment: If you were to do the scraping on the phone you can use javascript to grab DOM elements in order to retrieve values. This is usually preferable to trying to actually regex through tags or that kind of thing, as it tends to be more reliable and, usually, much faster.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use screen-scraping techniques.

Edit: I forgot the most common and important technique for this purpose: **RSS feeds**.
Most modern sites (including Stack Overflow) provide RSS feeds to share content. If they provide feeds, it means they allow you to reuse the content in your own Site or applications, maybe with some conditions that you can get from the T&C.

From the RSS feeds, you can recreate (part) of the Site as an app if you want. Or just use a feed reader to read it.

Comment: I wouldn't do that because everytime someone change some form your have to update the application. plus some website consider screen scraping to be an illegal use ... so if no API no iphone application IHMO

Comment: can you explain more about screen-scraping? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter if the website considers scraping illegal or not - as far as they can tell your app is simply another browser.  @userxxxxx - screen scraping is just your app pretending it's a browser.  You make an HTTP request and get back HTML, which your app parses to find items of interest.  It's basically like using a RSET API without the return values being formatted for easy parsing.  But as noted, it can be easily broken if the site changes.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no API and no other service you have two choices that I can think of:

1. Assuming you have the right to do so, screen-scraping is an option, as noted by **denni**. You retrieve the HTML and parse through it, sending GETs and POSTs to navigate through the site. When well-written a parser can usually survive changes to the website as long as they're not incredibly radical.
2. Work with the site to have them provide something you can work with that's more reliable. For many sites just a few lines of PHP in a protected directory will open up the data for easy parsing.